# Split up object array into rows

Tags: powershell

Consider a function that returns a list of object `X` where `X` has an integer and an *array* of objects.

```
Get-Foo

MyInteger   MyStrings
---------   ---------
        1   {A,B,C,D}
        2   {A,B,C}
        3   {A}
```

**How do I perform a self-join of this list in order to get the output below?**

```
Get-Foo

MyInteger   MyString
---------   --------
        1   A
        1   B
        1   C
        1   D
        2   A
        2   B
        2   C
        3   A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through MyStrings on each object, and create a new object for each one:

```
function get-foo {
[PSCustomObject]@{MyInteger=1;MyStrings=@('A','B','C','D')}
[PSCustomObject]@{MyInteger=2;MyStrings=@('A','B','C')}
[PSCustomObject]@{MyInteger=3;MyStrings=@('A')}
}

get-foo | 
foreach {
 foreach ($string in $_.MyStrings)
  { [PSCustomObject]@{
     MyInteger = $_.MyInteger
     MyString=$string
    }
   }
 } | ft -AutoSize

MyInteger MyString
--------- --------
        1 A       
        1 B       
        1 C       
        1 D       
        2 A       
        2 B       
        2 C       
        3 A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is `foreach` necessary to accomplish this? I struggled hard to get it working using piping only.

Comment: If you want to do this in the pipeline,you might want to look at the -PipelineVariable parameter in V4.  Don't know whether that will work with your function or not, though.